# Why no ambiguity when choosing between templated and non-templated functions with same signatures?

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer

The following code passes asserts:

```
int foo() { return 1; }

template<typename T>
int foo() { return 2; }

int main() {
  assert( 1 == foo() );
  assert( 2 == foo<int>() );
  return 0;
}
```

But to my understanding, according to Paragraph 13.3.3/1 of the C++11 Standard:

> [...] Given these definitions, a viable function `F1` is defined to be a better function than another viable function `F2` if for all arguments `i`, `ICSi(F1)` is not a worse conversion sequence than `ICSi(F2)`, and then [...] `F1` is a non-template function and `F2` is a function template specialization [...]

It should not, because signatures end up to be the same. So why is there no ambiguity when `foo<int>()` is called? What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The text you quote is rather dense; you have to read it carefully. "F1 is better than F2 if for all arguments `i`, ICSi(F1) **is not a worse conversion sequence** than ICSi(F2)" -- that's true here, since the two conversion sequences are the same, hence, neither is **worse than** the other. So now you move to the last part: "**and then** F1 is a non-template function and F2 is a function template specialization". That's true, so F1 is a better match than F2. Substituting `foo()` and `foo<int>()` for F1 and F2, respectively, the rule says that `foo()` is a better match than `foo<int>()`.

Whoops, I answered the wrong question. As the comment points out, the question is, why does explicitly calling `foo<int>()` not resolve to `foo()`? And the answer is, `foo<int>()` is a call to an explicit template instantiation, not a call to an overloaded function. Consider:

```
template <class Ty>
void f(Ty) { }

void f(int);
void g(int);

f(3.14);      // calls f<double> (overloaded function call)
f(1);         // calls f(int) (overloaded function call)
f<int>(3.14); // calls f<int> (explicit call of template instantiation)
g(3.14);      // calls g(int)
```

In this example, `f<int>` is the name of a template specialization. It is **not** the general function named `f`, so there is no overloading to consider, just like the call to `g(3.14)`.

Comment: What I don't get is why calling foo< int> is allowed since it boils down to the same signature as foo()? or are they considered different?

Comment: @z3dd Yes they are different: `foo<int>` is a template instantiation. So it can’t be the same as the non-template `foo`. You can’t refer to non-templates by providing template arguments. So there’s no ambiguity.